# There are 50 courses and 500 students. Ecah student will register 5 course from it. How could I tell if there exsit a time table with no conflict?

Tags: match, matching, genetic-algorithm, beam-search

I am doing a project that makes a `course-table`(location and time) for students that minimize their walking distance by using genetic algorithm.

There are 500 students and each of them will register for 3 mandatory courses out of 10 courses, and 2 elective courses out of 40 courses. So 50 courses in total and each student will have 5 classes to take.

For example:

student1 = [`(math100,0)`, `(phys100,1)`, `(chem100,2)`, `(art100,3)`, `(hist100,4)`].
This means for student1, his first class is `math100`, his second class is `phys100` and etc.

And the `course-table` will looks like:

```
|        Course       |      Location    |  Time Section    |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|       math 100      |     Building A   |        0         |
|       phys 100      |     Building B   |        1         |
|       chem 100      |     Building C   |        2         |
```

The problem I am facing right now is, how I know if there **exists** a `course-table` such that there is no time conflict for every student. By time conflict, I mean if there exist a student such that:

student1 = [`(math100,0)`, `(phys100,0)`, `(chem100,2)`, `(art100,2)`, `(hist100,4)`], then there is a time conflict.

To clarify, my question is given `students` like below:

```
student_1 = [`(math100)`, `(phys100)`, `(chem100)`, `(art100)`, `(hist100)`]
student_2 = [`(math101)`, `(phys101)`, `(chem101)`, `(art101)`, `(hist101)`]
...
student_n = [`(math100)`, `(phys100)`, `(chem100)`, `(art100)`, `(hist100)`]
```

How do I know if there exists a `course-table` that there is no time conflict?

Hoping for your ideas/helps!

Comment: Check on here, q&a exist that have answers you can edit to your situation.

Comment: What programming language? Python?